# Blackbody radiation as a stochastic process

Tags: statistical-mechanics, photons, thermal-radiation, stochastic-processes

Can one treat the blackbody radiation as a stochastic process of photon emission? If so, what stochastic process is it (perhaps a Poisson process?)?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_statistics): *An example of light that exhibits super-Poissonian statistics is thermal light.*

Comment: Related thread: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/434987/why-does-classical-light-always-result-in-super-poissonian-statistics

Comment: @Mauricio so what specific stochastic process is it?  ''super-Poissonian'' is perhaps a bit too general.

Comment: $(\Delta N)^2=\langle N\rangle (\langle N\rangle +1)$

Comment: @Mauricio I understand this is the variance of the photon count in a time window. I'm asking if this is described by some specific stochastic process?

Comment: Are you asking if the process has a name? It is at best called thermal or super-Poissonian. You can look for the whole derivation of the statistics in any photon statistics resource.

Comment: @Mauricio more like if there is a mathematical treatment that describes it as a [stochastic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process#:~:text=A%20stochastic%20or%20random%20process%20can%20be%20defined%20as%20a,is%20called%20the%20index%20set.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137551/discussion-between-mauricio-and-shadumu).