Are squeezed vacuum states classical?
After calculating their photon-number variance I tried to compute their second order coherence function, but it turns out larger than 3, implying it is a classical state.
Is it wrong? I expected it to be less than 1, thus proving it is a non-classical state.
After finding:
$$
\langle\hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}\rangle=\sinh(r)^2 
$$
$$
\langle\hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}\hat{a}\rangle = \cosh(r)^2 \sinh(r)^2+2\sinh(r)^4
$$
I calculated
$$
g^{(2)}(\tau)=\frac{\langle\hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}\hat{a}\rangle}{\langle\hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}\rangle^2} =\frac{1+\sinh(r)^2 + 2sinh(r)^2}{\sinh(r)^2} = 3 + \frac{1}{\sinh(r)^2}
$$

Your result is correct, but the condition $g^{(2)} <1$ is not a necessary condition for non-classicality, it is sufficient condition. A squeezed state can for example beat the shot-noise limit with appropriate measurements, something classical states cannot do.

what notion of classicality are you going with here? There's many possible definitions. Given the context you're probably going with $P$-nonclassicality. As discussed in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/434987/58382, classicality implies superpoissonian stats (ie $g^{(2)}\ge1$), but not the other way around.

Thanks!! My notes must be wrong
